# c# - How to encode a path to a pdf document to be used in an embed tag?

Tags: c#, html, urlencode

In my c# code I am embedding a string of an embed tag (to display a pdf on the web) into the DOM (asp.net site) and I noticed that the pdf fails to load the document when it's name has characters like an apostrophe.

What is the best way I can encode the path of the pdf document so that it will work for any url?

This didn't work:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

When I did this it worked though
src = src.Replace("'", "%27");
Is there a function that will url encode it like this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?query=url+encode&refinement=117

Comment: Did you try the function from that link? Did it work?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I tested `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`, they don't encode simple quotes.

You should write your own piece of code to do that.